# How to make global enums in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I tried to make a global folder named `enums` in the project root directory of nextjs, where I want to store all my global enums inside. But I didn't figure it out how to configure nextJS that it loads all declared enums inside of that folder as globals, so I don't need to import them in components.

Comment: Can you share how you import them into components? I'm struggling with that.